# Why can't I set SKScene(fileNamed:) in GameViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, viewcontroller, skscene

The relevant code is copied below and I also put a simple test project on Github to demonstrate this situation:

https://github.com/prinomen/viewPresentSceneTest

I have a `GameViewController` and a `GameScene` class. I try to set the scene with `SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")` but that call is not working because the scene does not appear and the print statement after that line is not being called.

I know I could use a different way to set the scene, like this:

```
let scene = GameScene()
```

But I'm trying to understand SpriteKit and it bothers me that the code below does not work. In another project I was able to successfully set the scene using `SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")` like in the code below.

Does anyone know why it is not working in this project?

**GameViewController.swift**

```
import SpriteKit
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            print("SKScene was set")
            // Set the scale mode fit the window:
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            // Size our scene to fit the view exactly:
            scene.size = view.bounds.size
            // Show the new scene:
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**GameScene.swift**

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    let logoText = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AvenirNext-Heavy")
    logoText.text = "Game Scene"
    logoText.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)
    logoText.fontSize = 60
    self.addChild(logoText)
  }
}
```

Comment: thecanteen's answer solved this. To fix my project I created a new GameScene.sks file and in its Custom Class inspector I entered `GameScene` in the Custom Class field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need an `.sks` file to load scenes like that. You probably deleted it from this project, but still kept it around in the other one.

Here's what the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483083-init) says:

> The name of the file, without a file extension. The file must be in
>   the app’s main bundle and have a .sks filename extension.

Comment: I searched for that initializer in the documentation for SKScene but it does not appear there... sometimes I forget that SKScene inherits from SKNode :) I should have checked there! Thanks for your help!